# Can I make some keyframes Bezier while keeping some as Linear (in Graph Editor)?

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, keyframes, graph-editor

I have a simple animation, and I want a certain keyframe to be Bezier in the graph editor, and another keyframe to stay Linear. But when I hit “T”> Bezier, it changes the entire animation to Bezier. **Is there a way to keep certain keyframes Linear while the desired keyframe to be Bezier?**

Answer (score 1):

Select the first keyframe and press <kbd>T</kbd> > *Linear*, select the second one and press <kbd>T</kbd> > *Bezier*, here is what it gives, you'll have a linear then a bezier interpolation:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it.
I just went to the keyframe’s side tab, and went to the “F-Curve” tab, and changed the Active Keyframe Interpolation from Linear, to Bezier.
[image]